# What happens to event listeners when element is removed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If, for example, I have series of event listeners created like this:

```
var els = document.getElementyById('myList').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener(eventType, function(e){ /* do stuff */ }, true);
}
```

First off, am I committing some kind of heresy like this? I mean, is there a faaar simpler way of doing this other than an event for each `<li>` element?

In either case, the main question is: what happens to those event listeners if the `<li>`s are removed/replaced? What would happen if I did this:

```
document.getElementyById('myList').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
```

Do the listeners stay 'suspended' thus slowing down the browser (assume I have *a lot* of `<li>`s), or are they automatically removed? Is it even an issue?

Comment: they are also garbage collected

Comment: @ArunPJohny ...meaning?

Comment: _"is there a faaar simpler way of doing this other than an event for each <li> element?"_ - Using a delegated handler attached to the containing `ul` element makes sense here. Not necessarily _simpler,_ but only slightly more complicated and more efficient - or maybe it is simpler if you are dynamically adding `li` elements. And it completely avoids the issue you are worried about.

Comment: Meaning they are removed from memory. Also, if every one of your events does the same thing, bind them to the encompassing <ul> - click events will bubble up from the lis to the ul.

Comment: If the same code is to be executed by the event, you'd want to at least create the function first and then reference it to the eventListener so you don't have multiple identical anonymous functions.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks a lot guys! Any one fancy writing an answer or shall I do it? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Event handlers assigned to destroyed elements are marked for garbage collection. Meaning they are removed from memory. Also, if every one of your events does the same thing, bind them to the encompassing `<ul>` - click events will bubble up from the `li`s to the `ul`.

Also,

> "is there a faaar simpler way of doing this other than an event for each `<li>` element?"
>
> Using a delegated handler attached to the containing ul element makes sense here.
> Not necessarily simpler, but only slightly more complicated and
> more efficient - or maybe it is simpler if you are dynamically adding li elements.
> And it completely avoids the issue you are worried about.

(Courtesy of @nnnnnn)

*Converted comment to answer as it seems to have helped answer the question.*